# Errno::EACCES: Permission denied @ unlink_internal when running rake test:models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

I'm playing with rails 4. I just created very simple test for my model but when I try to execute "rake test:models" I get following error:

```
C:\rails\project>rake test:models
DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
rake aborted!
Errno::EACCES: Permission denied @ unlink_internal - /tmp/db/new.sqlite3
C:/rails/project/test/test_helper.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
C:/rails/project/test/models/admin_test.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => test:models
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

My test database configuration looks as follows:

```
test:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: /tmp/db/new.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```

"/tmp/db" is directory where I have full access on my personal laptop.

Any ideas what could be source of this problem?

Answer (score 8):

One way I was able to get around this error was using

```
rake db:migrate rails_env=test
```

This generated the necessary migrations on my test.sqlite3

I believe the default setting for rails_env is "dev" but this may vary. I am still very new to rails but I hope this helps.

Comment: This is the correct approach. The migration has to be done in the specific environment where it wishes to be used.

Comment: maybe the default is development not dev, anyhow, no luck for me either when doing rails db:reset I get the permission denied error.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem with my `test.sqlite3` table and what worked for me was making a copy of my `development.sqlite3` table and renaming it `test.sqlite3`. I hope this works for you.

Comment: This worked for me too -- do the refactor, and then verify using file explorer.