# Command 'rake test' is not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I use Windows 7 (because I'm so lasy for installing Linux), and Ruby on Rails like a framework that I learn. I tried to write a command `rake test` in terminal, but

I get an error:

```
rake aborted!
Errno::EACCES: Permission denied @ unlink_internal
```

What it means? How to solve that problem and continue my studying?

Comment: does bundle exec rake test changes anything?

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/27280269/3563993

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running the below command

```
rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test
```

before running

```
rake test
```